# How can i add icon to React Link?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I have a cart link in my html file and it shows "cart" as a sitring when i display it. I want to replace "cart" string with a font awesome icon but since i used React to implement the code i could not find how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
<Link to="/cart">
 Cart
 {cartItems.length > 0 && (
  <span className="badge">{cartItems.length}</span>
 )}
 </Link>
```

and my cart curently displayed like that
[cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVWEf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a Font Awesome icon in React's render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116591/how-to-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-reacts-render)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faRandom } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Example = () => {
     return (
         <div>  
            <Link to="/any-url">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRandom} size="2x"/> 
              {cartItems.length > 0 && (<span className="badge">{cartItems.length}</span>)}         
            </Link> 
         </div>
     );
 };
```

To know more check this out: [Add link to Font Awesome icon in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200956/add-link-to-font-awesome-icon-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

**Use it something like this**

```js
<Link to="/cart">
Your font awesome icon here
 {cartItems.length > 0 && (
  <span className="badge">{cartItems.length}</span>
 )}
 </Link>
```

**Note:** don't forget to setup route for your "/cart" endpoint